# Normalized functions

Tags: function-construction, distributions

I'm looking for a smart way to define normalized functions. I usually write

```
f[x_] := f[x] = A Sin[x]/x;
```

Then I integrate the function

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> A > 0],
```

take the output and divide f by it

```
g[x_] :=g[x] = f[x]/(A \[Pi]).
```

Is there a better way than this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The integral needs to be done one way or another. You can use [`Normalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normalize.html) directly

```
f[x_] = Normalize[A Sinc[x], Integrate[#, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] &]

(* Sinc[x]/π *)
```

Verifying,

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(* 1 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can exploit the `Method -> "Normalize"` of `ProbabilityDistribution[]` for this:

```
PDF[ProbabilityDistribution[a Sinc[u], {u, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> Positive[a],
                            Method -> "Normalize"], x]
   Sinc[x]/π
```